# In core data, how does child context sync with parent context without using automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In core data, how does child context sync with parent context?
When the parent did some changes, without letting child context setting `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` to true. What would be other ways to properly sync between contexts?

Comment: Have you got a specific problem in mind, or is this just a general question? If you have code that's not working, can you add to the question please.

Comment: @AshleyMills it's not specifically happening but I reckon this would be an issue to me since in my project I do not specify `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent`. I wonder what would be other alternatives.